# Organize by folder in Aurelia

Tags: aurelia

I want a folder structure like so:

```
src/energy/
 -- energy.ts
 -- energy.html
 -- energyDataApi
 -- more files...
```

How do you set this up in Aurelia?

I've tried the feature setup: http://aurelia.io/hub.html#/doc/article/aurelia/framework/latest/app-configuration-and-startup/6, but keep getting a 404 on http://localhost:5000/dist/energy.js. I'm using ASP.Net Core, TypeScript, SystemJs, Gulp from the https://github.com/aurelia/skeleton-navigation/tree/master/skeleton-typescript-aspnetcore example.

main.ts

```
export function configure(aurelia: Aurelia) {
  aurelia.use
    .standardConfiguration()
    .developmentLogging()
    .feature('energy');
```

index.ts

```
export function configure(config) {
  config.globalResources(['./energy']);
}
```

Comment: Are you using JSPM/SystemJS, Webpack, or the Aurelia CLI?

Comment: @AshleyGrant please see my edit, JSPM/SystemJS

Comment: Would you mind posting your code to a GitHub repo that I could look at and see what's going wrong?

Comment: @AshleyGrant, I made a quick branch https://github.com/logankd/JQueryToAurelia/tree/aureliaFeatures. It is entirely possible I'm not thinking of features correctly, but I didn't find a good example to follow.

Comment: I figured out the issue. Your router config is pointing to a moduleId of `'energy'` but when you move your file in to a folder the moduleId is no longer there, it's at `energy/energy`. For what you are doing, there's no need to use the `feature` functionality. Just organize your pages in to feature folders like this and point your router to the correct place. I'd recommend closing the question b/c this might serve to confuse people in future google searches :-) I'll send your repo a PR.

Comment: That's great, thanks for the PR. Please add an answer below, so I can accept it and get you some points.

Comment: Nah, just close the question. I'll get points another time :-)